# can not get error in node.js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I wrote the code and execute but cannot get error message occurred in HTML. I use Eclipse and node.js with express and the GET method.

But when I enter IP and port and push submit, HTML show cHTMLt get ~ip=~;port=~

Is there something I have done wrong?

```
 index.ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
   </head>
<body>
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <form action="/testget" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="ip"> <p>
    <input type="text" name="port"> <p>
    <input type="submit">
     </form>
  </body>
  </html>

app.js
 var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 


if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

app.get('/testget', function(req,res){

    res.send(req.query.ip + ',' + req.query.port );
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
request.connection.remoteAddress 

or

const ip = req.socket.localAddress;
const port = req.socket.localPort;
```

Comment: Code only answers may solve the original problem, but some explanation of the solution makes for a much better answer. It can help others understand how to use your solution in similar situations.